# how to fix that ajax security?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, security

There is a way to inject code via ajax or to fake information?

Like to send Ajax from my website to another website that use ajax?

If so how can I prevent this that I can send ajax only from my website?

Comment: You are looking for the term `CSRF protection`.

Comment: The question is rather vague, but I concur with @arkascha, you seem to looking for CSRF protection.

Comment: What is CSRF where can I find a guide about that?

Comment: you can't send ajax calls to other website, unless it allows you to. About CSRF, I'm pretty sure taha I saw it in the internet, try there for starters.

Comment: Can't I use header() in php to see from where the request arrive?
Thank you for the CSRF I found a guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for CSRF (cross-site request forgery) protection. The issue is that your site has no idea where AJAX requests are coming from. The generally accepted solution is to create a token that is sent from your site which is required to be sent along with AJAX requests.

This token would be unique to a user session and output somewhere in the HTML of your page. This makes it challenging for other sites to capture this token.

To give you the basic idea, you would do something like this:

```
$_SESSION['csrf_token'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
```

Then you could for example output this as a JavaScript variable

```
<script>
window.CSRF_TOKEN = '<?php echo $_SESSION['csrf_token']; ?>';
</script>
```

If you happen to be using jQuery, you can use `ajaxSend()` to add the token to each request

```
$.ajaxSend(e, jqXHR, settings) {
  if (!settings.data) settings.data = {};
  settings.data['csrf_token'] = window.CSRF_TOKEN;
}
```

Finally, on the backend you would check that `$_REQUEST['csrf_token'] ==`$_SESSION['csrf_token']` to validate the request. It's generally a good idea for these tokens to be one-time use if possible. Storing the time the token was generated and making sure it's used within a reasonable time frame is also a good idea.